# Pointer arithmetic within a struct

Tags: c++, pointer-arithmetic

Within an array, pointer arithmetic is allowed (as long as the result doesn't exceed the bounds, where the end bound is one past the end of the array).

```
// Legit
int m[3] = {0, 1, 2};
int const *p = m;
std::cout << *p << *(p + 1) << *(p + 2) << std::endl;
```

Does the standard allow pointer arithmetic like this with a standard layout struct that contains consecutive member variables of the same fundamental type?

```
// Well defined???
struct MyStruct {
    int a, b, c;
};
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<MyStruct>);

MyStruct  m = {0, 1, 2};
int const *p = &m.a;
std::cout << *p << *(p + 1) << *(p + 2) << std::endl;
```

I certainly can compare pointers to the individual variables (i.e., `&m.a < &m.b`) because they are members of the same object, but I cannot determine whether `&m.a+1` is guaranteed to be `&m.b`.

I know this will likely work with most compilers, but I'm curious about what the standard says (C++20, if it matters).

Comment: I don't believe the standard guarantees this will work because the compiler is free to add padding between data members for reasons like alignment. But I don't know if there's any specific wording that says "this isn't guaranteed to work."

Comment: _"...A pointer to non-array object is treated as a pointer to the first element of an array with size 1...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic and as you know dereferencing 1 past the end (or greater) is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: _"...I certainly can compare pointers..."_  no you can only compare pointers that point to the same object `m.a` and `m.b` are different objects.  You can however use `std::less` to compare the pointers just not the builtin `operator<`

Comment: No, there is no such requirement. If you want to treat elements of an object as elements of an array, put them in an array.

Comment: Doesn't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58428562/accessing-struct-data-members-via-pointer-arithmetic answer your question?

Comment: Interesting...  If you placed a `union` in the struct...or used a `pragma pack` would the answer change?

Comment: @RichardCritten:  Thanks for that catch.  I got fooled by my search engine.  I queried for "c++ pointer relational operators" and the top hit was for C rather than C++, and that guarantee does exist in C.

Comment: @DL33:  Yes, thanks.  I failed to find that in my web searches.  And SO's "similar questions" box seemed to think my question was about PHP even though I tagged it as C++.

Answer (score 3):

#### From section `Additive operators`

(Emphasis mine)

> When an expression J that has integral type is added to or subtracted from an expression P of pointer type, the result has the type of P.
>
> - If P evaluates to a null pointer value and J evaluates to 0, the result is a null pointer value.
> - Otherwise, **if P points to an array element** i of an array object x with n elements the expressions P + J and J + P (where J has the value j) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) array element i + j [...]
> - **Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

Bottom line, no guarantees if the underlying type is not an array.

To your point, `std::is_standard_layout_v` provides guarantees regarding the layout itself, which can include guarantees for arrays contained in it, but it does not qualify the `struct` itself to be an array of elements, which the standard expects to use pointer arithmetics.

Comment: Note that this also forbids `&m.a < &m.b`.

Comment: @bitmask Oh yes ?! Aren't member of a structs/classes supposed to be layout in the order of declaration ? ... ;) _(I would be surprised that this expression is not guaranteed to be true...)_ _(especially for standard layout types)_ Am I wrong ? And if yes, why ? Please...

Comment: @Tenphase Two different objects. Doesn't matter that they are members of a third non-array object.

Comment: @bitmask No, that is allowed. From [expr.rel](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.rel#4.2) "If two pointers point to different non-static data members of the same object, ..., the pointer to the later declared member is required to compare greater provided the two members have the same access control ..."

Comment: @bitmask I'm a little lost on that one I must say... If standard layout type is trivially copyable _(it can be copied via memcpy)_, and members are layout in the order of declaration, the address of `a` in a `struct m` should be lower than the address of `b` within the same object... No ?! :o

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm It reassures me... _:P_ Otherwise, how would it be possible to `memcpy` it ? How would one be able to make cross-language APIs... ;) – _(which I did quite often...)_

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I stand corrected.