# std::span of non-array object in constant expressions cannot access elements but the first one

Tags: c++

I have the following `struct`:

```
struct Point
{
   double x, y, z;
};
```

that, for reasons, I want to see as a `std::span` of `double const` at compile-time, like this:

```
static constexpr Point p{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
constexpr std::span<double const, 3> s{ &p.x, 3 };
```

So far, so good; if I check the `extent` or access to the first element of the span at compile-time, everything is fine:

```
static_assert(s.extent == 3); // OK
static_assert(s[0] == p.x); // OK
```

but if I try to access any other element at compile-time, the code doesn't compile:

```
static_assert(s[1] == p.y); // does not compile
static_assert(s[2] == p.z); // does not compile
```

The code is rejected by all major compilers I tried with (MSVC, GCC, and Clang); [link to Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/zsvPYY1Eb).

The problem is that accessing any element but the first does not evaluate to a constant.
For example, the following is the error output that Clang emits:

```
<source>:16:19: error: static assertion expression is not an integral constant expression
   16 |     static_assert(s[1] == p.y);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:16:19: note: read of dereferenced one-past-the-end pointer is not allowed in a constant expression
<source>:17:19: error: static assertion expression is not an integral constant expression
   17 |     static_assert(s[2] == p.z);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.0.1/../../../../include/c++/14.0.1/span:287:24:
      note: cannot refer to element 2 of non-array object in a constant expression
  287 |         return *(this->_M_ptr + __idx);
      |                               ^
<source>:17:19: note: in call to 's.operator[](2)'
   17 |     static_assert(s[2] == p.z);
      |                   ^~~~
```

As far as I understand, the problem is that I am trying to see the underlying `Point` structure as an array of 3 `double`s but the compiler is smart enough to understand that it's not a real array, even if the memory layout of a `Point` should be the same of an array of 3 `double`s... or I am wrong?

Note that the same code (without the `constexpr` qualifiers) works at run-time, checking with run-time `assert`s.

So, my questions are:

- why is the code above invalid?
- is it invalid just at compile-time or even at run-time (maybe it's UB), despite it seems to work?
- is there a way to make it work at compile-time?

Thanks a lot for any support.

Comment: Re: "even if the memory layout of a `Point` should be the same of an array of 3 `double`s" -- there is no such requirement. Pretending that this `struct` is in fact an array results in undefined behavior.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58428562/accessing-struct-data-members-via-pointer-arithmetic. What you are doing is undefined behaviour, and constexpr in particular rejects a lot (if not all) cases of UB that compile normally - results are still undefined though.

Comment: Checkout `std::bit_cast`

Comment: OK. Let's say that for the platforms I have to support, I am sure that the 3 doubles of Point are contiguous in memory like an array, and that I can test it anyway. Would the program be unsafe anyway?

Comment: @StefanoBellotti -- the behavior is undefined. That means that the C++ language definition does not tell you what it does. If you can confirm that the compiler you're using does exactly what you need, that's okay. If you change compilers (and that includes changing compiler flags, in particular, optimization flags), then you need to re-assure yourself that the new compiler still does what you need.